# java script form validation wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried first time java script validation, i have done individually each field, when it comes to multiple fields,its not working,what steps i need to follow when i validate the can any one help me?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function  validation(){

    var nameval1=0;
    var nameval2=0;
    var nameval3=0;
    var myname=document.getElementById("myname").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
    var male=document.getElementById("male").value;
    var female=document.getElementById("female").value;

    // text box validation
    if(myname==""){
        alert("please enter name");
        nameval1=nameval1+1;
    }else{

         nameval1=0;
         }

        if(password==""){
        alert("please enter password");
        nameval2=nameval2+1;
    }else{

         nameval=0;
         }
    // gender validation
    if(male=="" && female==""){

        alert("please choose gender");
        nameval3=nameval3+1;
    }else{

         nameval3=0;
         }
    // returning value
    if((nameval1)!=0 && (nameval3)!=0 &&(nameval3)!=0){
        return false;
    }else
    {
        return true;
    }


    </script>

     </HEAD>

     <BODY>
     <form action="https://www.youtube.com" name=" " onSubmit=" return validation()">

    <fieldset>
    <label>Validation Form
        Name :      <input type="text"  name="name" id="myname"></br>

        Password : <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></br>

               <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender"> Male
               <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender"> Female
               </br>

        <input type='submit'  value='mysubmit'>
    </label>
    </fieldset>

     </form>
```

Comment: It would help us to know what you are expecting to happen and what is not working. Which part of your validation is broken when you go from individual validation to multiple validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myname=document.getElementById("myname").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
var male=document.getElementById("male").checked;
var female=document.getElementById("female").checked;
var flag = true;

// text box validation
    if(myname==""){
        alert("please enter name");
        flag = false;
    }
   else if(password==""){
        alert("please enter password");
        flag =false;
    }
   else if(male==false && female==false){
        alert("please choose gender");
        flag = false;
    }
    // returning value
    if(flag){
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgpy19jf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with alot less code by using `preventDefault` and checking for empty values/clicked radios:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){

  if($("#myname").val() == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Name cant be empty")    
  }

  if($("#password").val() == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Password cant be empty")    
  }

  if(!$("input[type=radio]").is(":checked")){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Gender cant be empty")    
  }

 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m40c5n18/)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you complicating things for yourself... Don't use javascript validation until and unless you are validating the data of fields. if the concern is only that the fields must be made compulsory..
 you can user the `required = "required"` attribute of the tags.

All browsers support it...

Comment: yes and no. 1. all *current* browsers support it but several older ones do not including (shocker) IE9 and below. Also several mobile browsers do not have support for it yet either. 2. It's not fool proof, in Safari it stops the form from validating but gives you no indication (such as an error message) that there is something wrong. And if you use something like Jquery Chosen it will also not give you a validation warning in any browser, leaving the user confused

Answer (score -2):

jmore009 already gave a good answer, but it had some issues.

Here is a [better FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m40c5n18/1/), made as an update to jmore009's solution.

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){

  if(!$("#myname").val().trim()){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Name can't be empty")    
  }

  if(!$("#password").val().trim()){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Password can't be empty")    
  }

    if(!$("input[type=radio]").is(":checked")){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Gender can't be empty")    
  }

});
```

And in case you don't know, include scripts right before the `</body>` tag. Otherwise JavaScript might not find necessary DOM elements due to different load time.

Comment: uhhh the only thing you added was `.trim()` to remove whitespace. Yes that's nice as well and can be added (you could also break down validations alot more than this...which is just a simple example) but to say `but it had some issues.` and `Here is a better FIDDLE` is pretty ridiculous considering this is 98% my code

Comment: I am sorry if it sounds ridiculous. English is not my mother tongue and I totally did not want to say that your script was wrong and that it is my own script.

What I wanted to say is that although it is the right solution, there were `==` equality operators (which is considered a bad practice). Also, checking if something is `x == ""` can be written as `!x`.

I admit that it is your code and `issues` may not be the right word, but I didn't come up with anything better, yet I wanted to update your script.

Comment: Next time, consider commenting on the other user's answer to suggest minor improvements.